# Magento CE 1.7 - not sending invoice emails to customer

Tags: magento, email, invoice

we're using Magento CE 1.7 and EasyPDF Invoice. This extension attaches a PDF to the order-, invoice- and shipment-emails automaticly. This works fine for the following cases:

- order email: customer + admin
- shipment email: customer + admin
- invoice email: admin

works not for:

- invoice email: customer

When I click the "send email"-button from the backend/invoices our customer + the admin receives an invoice-email. But when it comes to the automatic process the customer is left without the invoice/email.

- Email Templates are set
- Sales Emails: Invoice active
- EasyPDF: Invoice Email: customer + admin

Have someone a clue, why the email isn't sent to our customer (but at the same time is sent to the admin)?
This problem occurs with imported orders from ebay (M2E Pro) and with a standard checkout in our magento shop (and every single payment option)

Thanks & best regards

Andrew

Comment: Check this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8389/paypal-payment-pro-the-invoice-email-is-not-sent

Comment: So it's not a bug, it's a feature...? Someone know an extension (observer), that sends the invoice emails for customers automaticly?

Comment: You may need to customize